# Stuck on Recovery Mode 3.0 screen in Redmi Y2

Tags: boot, xiaomi

My Redmi Y2 phone was working fine for long time but suddenly I found that "VOLUME UP" key is not working so I tried to restart the phone but it got stuck into Recovery 3.0 screen. It only gives 3 options:

- Reboot
- Wipe Data
- Connect with MIAssistant

Pressing on "Reboot" displays two option:

- Reboot to System
- Go bak to Main Menu

Pressing "Reboot to System" reboots device and again goes back to "Recovery 3.0" screen, this keeps going on. I don't want to loss data so I didn't try "Wipe Data" option. Its not moving out of this screen no matter how may times I reboot it. I tried FAST BOOT by pressing (VOLUME DOWN + POWER) button but it has no effect, it shows logo for a moment and ended up to same "Recovery 3.0" screen.

[image]